how do I show that multiplicative noise stabilizes the solution to the SDE?
Say that I am given the stochastic differential equation $dX=k dt - \sigma x dW$, where $k$ is constant. I can find the mean of this process using either Ito or Stratonovich interpretations, but both give a solution that blows up. However, a quick simulation of this process shows that the multiplicative noise stabilizes the mean and that it levels off with time. How do I show that mathematically for the given process?
Attempt at the solutions: I used Ito's lemma to find the SDE for $y=ln(x)$ and it is given by $dY=(k e^{-y} - \sigma^2/2) dt +\sigma dW$. This process clearly shows a negative drift term dominating as $y$ increases because of the decaying exponential term. To me, this shows that, since the mean of $y$ levels off, the mean of $x$ levels off, but I can't quite understand why either interpretation of the SDE for x does not show that leveling-off behavior.
In summary, my question is how to use the equation $dX=k dt - \sigma x dW$ to show that the mean levels off due to the effect of the multiplicative noise. Do I need to always make a change of variables that transfers the equation into an equation with additive noise instead of multiplicative to show that?


Ito or Stratonovich: please make up your mind. I will choose Ito and let you handle the Stratonovich case.

The mean is obviously
$$
\mathbb E[X_t]=kt
$$
regardless what the noise $\int_0^t\sigma X_s\,dW_s$ is doing because the expectation of that Ito integral is zero.

As far as I understand English, the mean levels off (neither rises nor falls) if and only if $k=0\,.$

The SDE is one of the few explicitly solvable ones which gives
$$
X_t=\Phi_t\left(X_0+\int_0^t\frac{ks}{\Phi_s}\,ds\right)
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\Phi_t=\exp\left(-\sigma W_t-\frac{\sigma^2t}2\right)\,.
$$

In what sense does this solution "blow up" ?


